# Transient fields disappearing in hibernate interceptor

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Hibernate interceptor which I have written in order to save certain @Transient fields of an @Entity class to a Quartz scheduler. However, these transient fields are all cleared before it reaches the interceptor class. Is there any way to tell Hibernate not to delete the fields' values before hitting the Interceptor class?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a long time ago but did you find any answer?

Comment: Unfortuantely no, I ended up finding a separate workaround though honestly I can't remember what it was.

Comment: It's alright :-) Thanks for answering though. I ended up using Spring's AOP which was even better in my case